# Use Regex for phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a Regex.

```
let phones = ['321-1234567','+355 321 1234567','0103 1234500', '00 355 3211234567' ]
```

I want to have the following results:

```
3211234567
+3553211234567
+3551031234500
+3553211234567
```

I have implemented this:

```
phones.forEach(phone => {
      phone = phone.replace(/^0+/,'+355').replace(/[^+\d]+/g, '')
      console.log(phone)
    })
```

Output:

```
3211234567
+3553211234567
+3551031234500
+3553553211234567 --->wrong , it should be: +3553211234567
```

and it works only for the three first elements of array, but it doesn't work for the last one (the case when we should replace those two zeros with + ).

**So, when the phone number starts with a zero, replace that first zero with +355, when it starts with 00, replace those two zeros with + .**

How can I do that using a Regex, or should I use conditions like `if phone.startsWith()`?

My question is not a duplication of: [Format a phone number (get rid of empty spaces and replace the first digit if it's 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69193376/format-a-phone-number-get-rid-of-empty-spaces-and-replace-the-first-digit-if-it/69193578#69193578)

as the solution there doesn't take in consideration the case when the phone number starts with 00 355 .

Comment: `0+` means 1 or more zeros. Try changing it to `0{1}` which means exactly one zero.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69193578/9758194) not working for you?

Comment: @JvdV, that doesn't include the last case: when the phone number starts with 00, replace 00 with +. It includes only the case when phone number starts with one 0, replace it with +355

Comment: @evolutionxbox the last phone number in the array doesn't work with that regex: when the phone number starts with 00, replace 00 with +. It includes only the case when phone number starts with one 0, replace it with +355

Comment: @Ani, seems to work for me though even when the number starts with 00. Did you check the answer I gave? Not the accepted answer?

Comment: @JvdV Your solution yields `+3553211234567` for the first test case here, while `3211234567` is expected.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, ok, that's not what OP mentioned. Either way, that's a small fix. Though not an expert in JS at all, I'd maybe use `console.log((str.startsWith('0') || str.startsWith('+') ? '+355' : '') + array.join(''));` as the last line then.

Comment: Yes. The point is, should this post be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it is not a duplicate question but the people who voted for closing, have not read the question in details. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let phones = ['321-1234567','+355 321 1234567','0103 1234500', '00 355 3211234567' ]

phones = phones.map(r => r
  .replace(/^00/,'+')
  .replace(/^0/,'+355')
  .replace(/[^+\d]+/g, '')
)

console.log(phones)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```js
let phones = ['321-1234567','+355 321 1234567','0103 1234500', '00 355 3211234567' ]
for (const phone of phones) {
  console.log(
      phone.replace(/^0{1,2}/, (x) => x=='00'?'+':'+355')
           .replace(/(?!^\+)\D/g, ''))
}
```

*Details*:

- `.replace(/^0{1,2}/, (x) => x=='00'?'+':'+355')` - matches `00` or `0` at the start of string, and if the match is `00`, replacement is `+`, else, replacement is `+355` (here, `x` stands for the whole match value and `if ? then : else` is a ternary operator)
- `.replace(/(?!^\+)\D/g, '')` removes any non-digit if it is not `+` at the start of string.

*Regex details*:

- `^0{1,2}` - `^` matches start of string and `0{1,2}` matches one or two zero chars
- `(?!^\+)\D` - `(?!^\+)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if the char immediately to the right is `+` that is located at the start of the string (due to `^` anchor), and `\D` matches any char other than a digit.

Comment: Thank your for your solution, it works perfectly but I find the other solution a bit easier to understand.

Comment: @Ani So, if there is a `+` in the middle or end of string, you want to keep it? What is not clear?

Comment: I didn't thought about the case when there might be + in the middle of end of string, so I'm going to use this part: .replace(/(?!^\+)\D/g, '') . that's why I voted up your solution. :) and thanks for the details too, I really appreciate it as I am new to Regex.

Answer (score -1):

your only problem is in this line `replace(/^0+/,'+355')` replace this with `replace(/^0+/,'+')`

```
phones.forEach(phone => {
      phone = phone.replace(/^0+/,'+').replace(/[^+\d]+/g, '')
      console.log(phone)
    })
```